# Does an insulator always contain the Fermi surface in the 1st BZ

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, metals, insulators, fermi-energy

I'm looking for a clarification about the classification of metals and insulators;

is it correct to state that ***if the Fermi surface is contained into the first BZ, then the material is an insulator, while if not is a metal***?

If it is like that, why is that?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Constructing a metal who's Fermi surface is contained in the 1st BZ is pretty straitforward (consider a standard tight binding model with a small filling factor). Constructing an insulator where the Fermi surface crosses the BZ boundry is more tricky but I see no reason in principle why you can't

Comment: So what does it mean that the Fermi surface is contained into the first BZ? What kind of information brings to the knowledge on the conductivity of the material?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, after some researches I found out that in order to be an insulator, the fermi surface's volume has to fill **exactly** the volume of the Brillouin zone. This means that the volume of the two has to match, but also that a sufficlently strong potential is required in order to deform the fermi surface to fit perfectly in the BZ. This should be an insulator.

EDIT:  If the Fermi level is higher than the band, and lies in a bandgap, and there is no crossing between different bands, that forces the Fermi surface to conform to the highest filled Brillouin Zone. There is no fine-tuned matching needed to make it "fit", thanks to @Rococo

Comment: "a sufficiently strong potential is required in order to deform the fermi surface to fit perfectly in the BZ" I think you are confused on this point. If the Fermi level is higher than the band, and lies in a bandgap, and there is no crossing between different bands, that forces the Fermi surface to conform to the highest filled Brillouin Zone. There is no fine-tuned matching needed to make it "fit".

Comment: Nice, thank you for the clarification.